# In the VS2010 debugger, how do I change an object value without changing its implicit type?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, debugging

I am using Visual Studio 2010 (Professional). In my program, I have an object array containing byte objects which are cast to a byte array:

```
public byte[] myMethod(object[] someBytes)
{ // Breakpoint is set here
     return someBytes.Cast<byte>().ToArray();
}
```

For testing purposes, I want to change the values of the object array someBytes. When the debugging is breaked at the breakpoint, I can do this manually in the dropdown list that appears when I hover over someBytes. However, changing one of the object values leads to a problem: The cast does no longer work for this value, and I get an InvalidCastException.

This seems to indicate that the object structure is not maintained when manipulated with the debugger, but why is this the case? And how can it be avoided, so that I can modify the byte value?

There is a cumbersome possibility to modify the value directly via the memory window, but that is a solution I would like to avoid if possible.

Comment: Try casting to byte when you assign.  For example, instead of assigning "5", assign "(byte)5".  Problem is that the array is of type object and the C# compiler defaults numeric literals to be `int` rather than `byte`

Comment: Thank you, this worked fine. Should be the correct answer, but I can't mark a comment as correct.